# Where do I handle the WPF commands?

Tags: wpf

I have a whole bunch of `RoutedUICommand` commands which I fire from different places, using the `Command` attribute in XAML.

They all are bound right now in my `MainWindow.xaml` and in my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` I have a handler for each of them. I have set it up this way, mostly because I resolve the `MainWindow` class with Unity and it receives all necessary dependencies (i.e. domain services and etc). If I bind the command to a UserControl, I wouldn't have those services available there and also it seems wrong that a UserControl which is given a DataContext, but would be allowed to manipulate its or another context.

My question: does this seem right? To me, something seems off about handling all of the commands in a single central place, especially the main window code behind.

I am new to WPF and can't tell if this is right or wrong. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some background info: Are you familiar with how the MVVM pattern is supposed to work? (It's fine if you don't know yet, I just want to know whether possible answers can simply use the terms related to MVVM without any further explanation, or whether they should be a bit more verbose about that.)

Comment: I know the MVVM pattern in theory, but it is the first time I use it. As far as I know, WPF works best with it, so I am trying to follow the pattern here. That's why I have bindings and not events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle them in your `ViewModel`. The common pattern in WPF applications is [MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx).

- M - model (i.e. DB)
- V - view (.xaml files)
- VM - a class that is set to be the `DataContext` for you view. You should do all the logic, binding here.

I suggest having a look at some MVVM frameworks that can simplify the development.

Some of the popular ones are:

- [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.com)
- [MVVM Light](http://www.mvvmlight.net)

Comment: Ok, so if I have a user control placed in MainWindow.xaml which is supposed to render, let's say a list of items - I don't provide the `DataContext` to that user control from the MainWindow.xaml, instead - the VM for the user control should get the data itself?

Comment: @HristoYankov yes, it might be that the UserControl gets the values itself. But you cold also have a VM for the whole screen that gets the data and passes it to the children VMs. It depends on what granularity you want to achieve. Sometimes it doesn't make sense for every little control to get the data from the DB as i.e. they might share some data and it's better to get it in one place

Comment: I am using MahApps Metro and I want to use Caliburn.Micro. Should I get the Caliburn.Metro package?

Comment: @HristoYankov accoring to what I read on the project page it is most likely correct package for you

Answer (score 1):

WPF provides two implementations of the ICommand interface; the System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand and System.Windows.Input.RoutedUICommand where the latter is a subclass of the former that simply adds a Text property that describes the command.

However, neither of these implementations are especially suited to be used in a view model as they search the visual tree from the focused element and up for an element that has a matching System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding object in its CommandBindings collection and then executes the Execute delegate for this particular CommandBinding.

Since the command logic should reside in the view model, you don’t want to setup a CommandBinding in the view in order to connect the command to a visual element. Instead you should create your own command by creating a class that implements the ICommand. All MVVM libraries out there such as Prism, MvvmLight and Caliburn Micro already have such an implementation. They are usually called DelegateCommand or RelayCommand. Please refer to the following links for more information about commands and how to use them in an MVVM WPF application.

**MVVM - Commands, RelayCommands and EventToCommand:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx

**Handling events in an MVVM WPF application:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/